# How to require Friends Online Presence as non-revocable permission on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-oauth

I would like a new user of my canvas app to grant the "friends_online_presence" permission.

On the FB manual page, this permission is listed among the "User and friends Permissions" which should appear on the first page of the registration dialogue and should be non-revocable.

However, Facebook does the opposite - it redirects the user to the second page of the dialogue, where this permission is optional for the user.

If I try to make registration with other permissions from the list (i.e. friends_likes), it works as supposed - the permission is requested as non-revocable on the first screen.

Am I doing something wrong or this is actually a bug in their documentation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a bug in their documentation.  You can however, check to see which permissions the user accepted.  If you find they allowed your app, but not the friends permissions, you can give the user a specific screen telling them they can't use your app.